# Mysql Stored Procedures - Returning Message

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, return-value

It's a bit silly asking homework questions here, however I'm genuinely stumped as to what this question is asking.

> Create a stored procedure to add
>   results. The procedure should take
>   four (4) parameters. These are; The
>   student's name (first and last), the
>   name of the apparatus and the score.
>   **When the data has been inserted,
>   return a message to the user advising
>   that the data has been inserted.** Name
>   the procedure, addresults_xxx(), where
>   xxx is to be replaced by your
>   initials. Include the date.

I've highlighted the part in bold that I don't understand.

This is what I have so far.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE addresults_JB( IN student_first_name VARCHAR(20),
                IN student_last_name VARCHAR(20),
                IN apparatus_name VARCHAR(20),
                IN test_result INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE student_id INT;
    DECLARE apparatus_id INT;

    SELECT studentid INTO student_id
    FROM tblstudents
    WHERE studentfirstname = student_first_name
    AND studentlastname = student_last_name;

    SELECT apparatusid INTO apparatus_id
    FROM tblapparatus
    WHERE apparatusname = apparatus_name;


    INSERT INTO tblresults (studentid, apparatusid, result, date_added)
    VALUES  (student_id, apparatus_id, test_result, NOW());

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

How can I return a message from a stored procedure?

Comment: Related: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/197706

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, unfortuately I don't think there is a Print command like in MS SQL.

```
select "Procedure Completed" as "Result";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:
SELECT "The data has been inserted"

Comment: Thanks for answering, you both said the same thing so I had to accept the first answer I received!